# C++ make_shared not available

Tags: c++, tr1, make-shared

While I have `std::tr1::shared_ptr<T>` available in my compiler, I don't
have `make_shared`.

Can someone point me to a proper implementation of `make_shared`? I see
that I need to use varargs to provide arguments to constructor of T.

But I don't have variadic templates available in my compiler as well.

Comment: Without variadic templates, you'll need multiple versions of `make_shared`, one for zero arguments, one for one argument, one for two arguments, etc.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Variadic templates are not a massive stumbling point, though. The absence of rvalue references makes `make_shared` less powerful in C++03, but you could still have the single-allocation implementation optimization, as well as the exception-safetly that a factory function provides.

Comment: @Ben: worse: you need two for one argument, four for two arguments, eight for three arguments, etc.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Enlighten me, what varies between the two versions of each argument?

Comment: you can copy an existing implementations (from boost or compilers supporting the latest standard but not using variadic templates) and use that. I have one lying around but it's msvc only as it depends on their std::tr1::_Ref_count_base and _Enable_shared

Comment: @Ben: it's `T const&` vs `T&`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Oh, `T` can be explicitly specified as `const something`, but won't infer that way?  Yeah it looks that way: http://ideone.com/c3VF8

Comment: @Ben: exactly. `T&` will not deduce `foo const&`, only `foo&`. That's why Kerrek mentions rvalue references: `T&&` can deduce both as `foo&` or `foo&&`

Answer (score 6):

If your compiler don't give an implementation of make_shared and you can't use boost, and you don't mind the lack of single-allocation optimization both for the object and the reference counter then make_shared is something like this:

**Without variadic template support**:

```
// zero arguments version
template <typename T>
inline shared_ptr<T> make_shared()
{
  return shared_ptr<T>(new T());
}

// one argument version
template <typename T, typename Arg1>
inline shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Arg1&& arg1)
{
  return shared_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Arg1>(arg1)));
}

// two arguments version
template <typename T, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
inline shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Arg1&& arg1, Arg2&& arg2)
{
  return shared_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Arg1>(arg1),
                             std::forward<Arg2>(arg2)));
}

// ...
```

If your compiler don't support r-value references, then make 2 versions for each arguments count: one *const Arg&* and one *Arg&*

**With variadic template support**:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
inline shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Args&&... args)
{
  return shared_ptr<T>(new T( std::forward<Args>(args)... ));
}
```

Comment: Gigi's variadic version also leaves a proper backtrace as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233358/debuggable-replacement-for-make-shared