# Debuggable replacement for make_shared()

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, backtrace, make-shared

Using gcc 4.6.2, make_shared() gives a useless backtrace (apparently due to some rethrow) if a constructor throws an exception.  I'm using make_shared() to save a bit of typing, but this is show stopper.  I've created a substitute **make_shrd()** that allows a normal backtrace.  I'm using gdb 7.3.1.

I'm worried that:

1. The bad backtrace under make_shared() is somehow my own fault
2. My substitute make_shrd() will cause me subtle problems.

Here's a demo:

```
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

class foo1
{
public:
        foo1( const string& bar, int x ) :m_bar(bar), m_x(x)
        {
                throw logic_error( "Huh?" );
        }
        string m_bar;
        int m_x;
};

class foo2
{
public:
        foo2( const string& bar, int x ) : m_foo1(bar,x)
        {}

        foo1  m_foo1;
};

// more debuggable substitute for make_shared() ??
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr<T> make_shrd( Args... args )
{
        return std::shared_ptr<T>( new T(args...));
}

int main()
{
        auto p_foo2 = make_shared<foo2>( "stuff", 5 );          // debug BAD!!
//      auto p_foo2 = make_shrd<foo2>( "stuff", 5 );            // debug OK
//      auto p_foo2 = new foo2( "stuff", 5 );                   // debug OK
//      auto p_foo2 = shared_ptr<foo2>(new foo2( "stuff", 5 )); // debug OK
        return (int)(long int)p_foo2;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ -g -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra main.cpp
```

Debugged with:

```
gdb a.out
```

The make_shared() backtrace is junk that does not show the stack to the point of the exception.  All the other options provide a sane backtrace.

Thanks in advance for help and suggestions.

Comment: You need perfect forwarding for a start... Add `&&` and `std::forward<>` to `make_shrd` and it should be fine, though you're still missing out on the allocation optimization provided by `std::make_shared`.

Comment: Ultimately this just seems like a QOI issue in GCC 4.6. Have you tried GCC 4.7 yet?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135144/c-make-shared-not-available/9136228#9136228 for a simple roll-your-own make_shared

Comment: @Gigi, The backtrace with your version is fine.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation of `make_shrd()` looses the ability to allocate just one chunk of memory: `std::make_shared()` does two things:

1. it avoids duplicating of writing the type (if the type of the allocation and the type of the desired `std::shared_ptr<T>` are the same rather than the latter being for a base class)
2. it combines allocation of the shared object and the object's descriptor into just one allocation

The main purpose of `std::make_shared()` is actually the second feature. I haven't looked at the implementation but I suspect that this is also the part which actually causes you problems. Other than that, I don't see any reason why your implementation is any worse once you fix forwarding of arguments:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr<T> make_shrd(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Comment: Note that the combining of the allocation of the shared block is not *mandated* by the specification. Virtually every implementation will do it, but it's not *required*. Of course, having shared block at all is not technically required either, but every `shared_ptr` implementation does.

Comment: There is a third reason for `make_shared`: It avoids memory leaks. Consider a function call `f(std::shared_ptr<X>(new X(...)), std::shared_ptr<Y>(new Y(...)))`. The compiler could execute `new X(...)` first, then `new Y(...)` _before_ passing the `X*` to the `std::shared_ptr<X>`. When `new Y(...)` throws an exception, you have a memory leak. Replace it with `f(std::make_shared<X>(...), std::make_shared<Y>(...))` and the (possible) leak is gone.