# std::shared_ptr initialization: make_shared<Foo>() vs shared_ptr<T>(new Foo)

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

What's the difference between:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p = std::shared_ptr<int>( new int );
```

and

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p = std::make_shared< int >();
```

?

Which one should I prefer and why?

P. S. Pretty sure this must have been answered already, but I can't find a similar question.

Comment: The second has to be `std::make_shared<int>()`.

Comment: Yes, but not in this case. Always use `make_shared`. See the following URL for more information: http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/

Comment: @Deduplicator: how the hell is my question a duplicate of one asked a year later?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: I *think* the other one is a slightly better, and they cover the same territory. Age only comes in as a tie-breaker (even though it's unfortunately too prominent in the explanatory text), and older questions have a higher chance to be well-polished.

Comment: @Deduplicator: fair enough. Although I think my title is clearer, too.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Both examples are rather more verbose than necessary:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int);  // or '=shared_ptr<int>(new int)' if you insist
auto p = std::make_shared<int>(); // or 'std::shared_ptr<int> p' if you insist
```

> What's the difference?

The main difference is that the first requires two memory allocations: one for the managed object (`new int`), and one for the reference count. `make_shared` should allocate a single block of memory, and create both in that.

> Which one should I prefer and why?

You should usually use `make_shared` as it's more efficient. As noted in another answer, it also avoids any possibility of a memory leak, since you never have a raw pointer to the managed object.

However, as noted in the comments, it has a potential disadvantage that the memory won't be released when the object is destroyed, if there are still weak pointers preventing the shared count from being deleted.

---

**EDIT 2020/03/06:**

Further recommendations come also from the [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/how-to-create-and-use-shared-ptr-instances?view=vs-2019) with associated examples. Keep the focus on the **Example 1** snippet:

> Whenever possible, use the make_shared function to create a shared_ptr
> when the memory resource is created for the first time. make_shared is
> exception-safe. It uses the same call to allocate the memory for the
> control block and the resource, which reduces the construction
> overhead. If you don't use make_shared, then you have to use an
> explicit new expression to create the object before you pass it to the
> shared_ptr constructor. The following example shows various ways to
> declare and initialize a shared_ptr together with a new object.

Comment: It has a disadvantage: The memory block is kept around for as long as there are weak-pointers to the object.

Comment: @Xeo: Thanks, I'd forgotten about that.

Comment: +1 for the weak pointer comment. nice.

Comment: @Xeo Can you elaborate a little bit on weak ptr issue? Weak pointers were created not to hold memory so why it is the case in this situation?

Comment: @Trismegistos: Because the shared block, that holds the data and counters for weak and shared pointers, can only be released after the last associated `weak_ptr` has been destroyed - otherwise, how would the `weak_ptr` know that its parent is gone?

Comment: @Xeo Why is this the case with make_shared but not the case with std::shared_ptr constructor?

Comment: @Trismegistos: The block not being freed is the same for both. What's different is that `make_shared` puts the shared object _into_ that block, while normal construction from a pointer stores just that - the pointer, which can be freed as soon as the shared count hits 0.

Answer (score 27):

From [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)

In contrast, the declaration `std::shared_ptr<T> p(new T(Args...))` **performs at least two memory allocations, which may incur unnecessary overhead.**

Moreover, `f(shared_ptr<int>(new int(42)), g())` **can lead to memory leak if g throws an exception. This problem doesn't exist if make_shared is used.**

So I would recommend the `make_shared` approach if possible.

Comment: Thanks. Too bad there are problems with `shared_ptr` and `make_shared` on Mac (they're still in `tr1` namespace so I have to define macros to write portable code using shared pointers). I mean, additional macro is required to use `make_shared`.

Comment: That's bad yeah. Which compiler are you using? In Debian `g++ 4.7` doesn't have that problem.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe:  On the Mac you can specify -stdlib=libc++ (in Xcode find "C++ Standard Library" in build settings and choose "libc++").  This will get you a C++11 std::lib.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Hm! Is it official? As in not buggy?

Comment: Apple is officially supporting it back to 10.7, and indefinitely forward.

Comment: @AdriC.S.: `clang` is now official compiler for Mac, and Apple doesn't update it often.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135144/c-make-shared-not-available) post? If you can't have `make_shared` with your current compiler, maybe the solution in there might help.

Answer (score 13):

Be aware that `make_shared` limits you to using the default allocation/deallocation functions so if you want to have more control, `make_shared` is not an option. In other words, something like

```
std::shared_ptr<uint8_t>(p, [](uint8_t *p){ /*user code */});
```

is impossible using `make_shared`. One could use `allocate_shared` instead, but only the allocator can be specified, not a deleter. Sometimes one need to control allocation and deletion of the wrapped class.