# Initializing a vector of pointers to vector

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I have this vector of pointers to vector:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>> vec;
```

I want to initialize the first pointer to be a pointer to an empty vector. I tried this:

```
vec.push_back(nullptr);
```

Then I want to push_back some value to the vector where the nullptr points. I did this:

```
vec[0]->push_back(x);
```

Which I know is wrong, it ends up in segfault. I tried to do something with make_shared() instead of nullptr, but I still can't figure out how to achieve what I mentioned. Could anyone help me fix this example?

Comment: `nullptr` is **never** "a pointer to an empty vector".

Comment: _"I tried to do something with make_shared() instead of nullptr"_ You should show us your attempt, so that we can correct it.

Comment: I have my doubts you really want a vector of vector pointers at all. What is the problem you are using this to solve?

Comment: You can directly initialise it with 1 element `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>> vec { std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>() };`

Answer (score 7):

If you want `vec` to contain one valid shared pointer to a vector, it's as simple as

```
vec.emplace_back(std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>());
```

Now there's pointer there, and it points at valid object. Making your subsequent sub-scripting and dereference valid themselves.

Just be sure you don't do it *second*. If you insert a `nullptr` first, and then a valid pointer, then it will be `vec[1]` that points at an object, not `vec[0]`. Your original attempt places an empty shared pointer at the start of the vector. And it doesn't go anywhere if you insert more elements after it.

Comment: Just to add to this, I had a question about `new` vs `make_shared` in this context.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301511/stdshared-ptr-initialization-make-sharedfoo-vs-shared-ptrtnew-foo#18301738) answered that.