# Why instantiating a shared_ptr calling destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Can someone explain why is the destructor of class `bar` being called in the line where the object of the same type is being initialized?

```
    #include <memory>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class bar
    {
      public:
        bar() {}

        ~bar() { std::cout << "destructor called " << std::endl; }
    };

    class foo
    {
      public:
        foo(std::shared_ptr<bar> barP) {}
    };


    int main() {

        std::shared_ptr<foo> f;
        std::cout << "before init " << std::endl;
        f = std::shared_ptr<foo>(new foo(std::shared_ptr<bar>(new bar())));
        std::cout << "after init"  << std::endl;
    }
```

Output:

```
before init 
destructor called 
after init
```

Comment: foo's constructor takes ownership of `barP`, but doesn't do anything with it. Which `shared_ptr<>` are you expecting maintains a ref-count on `bar` after the `f=...` line is over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement:

```
f = std::shared_ptr<foo>(new foo(std::shared_ptr<bar>(new bar())));
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

constructs a temporary `shared_ptr` which goes out of scope at the end of the statement.  At that point, the `shared_ptr` goes away, taking `bar` with it (since no copies of the `shared_ptr` remain alive).

But if you change `foo` to read like this:

```
class foo
{
  public:
    foo(std::shared_ptr<bar> barP) { m_bar = barP; }
    std::shared_ptr<bar> m_bar;
};
```

Then the output you get is probably what you were expecting, because `foo` maintains a copy of the `shared_ptr` until it (`foo`) goes out of scope and that copy keeps `bar` alive:

```
before init 
after init
destructor called
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qeyaaqGK1dptT6en)

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `bar` instance only lives as long as the duration of the `foo` constructor.  So it gets constructed, passed into the `shared_ptr`, which is then into the `foo` constructor.  As soon as that constructor is done (even if on the same line) the expression itself is done, and so the `shared_ptr` is done, and destructs.

At the end of `main` right before the `cout`, you still have a `shared_ptr` to foo in `f`, but the unnamed `shared_ptr` to your `bar` object has already gone "out of scope".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not instantiate `shared_ptr` in this way, use `make_shared` to instantiate `shared_ptr`. Please check the modified code -

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class bar
{
  public:
    bar() {}

    ~bar() { std::cout << "destructor called " << std::endl; }
};

class foo
{
  public:
    foo(std::shared_ptr<bar> barP) {}
};


int main() {

    std::shared_ptr<foo> f;
    std::cout << "before init " << std::endl;
    std::shared_ptr<bar> b = std::make_shared<bar>();
    f = std::make_shared<foo>(b);
    std::cout << "after init"  << std::endl;
}
```

**The output of the above program -**

```
before init 
after init
destructor called
```

Generally, what is happening with your code is you are passing `new bar` to the constructor of `foo`. And no one is holding the ownership of `bar` shared pointer. So, the ref count is becoming 0 and it is being deleted, hence the destructor is being called.

**Further Read**: [make_shared vs new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301511/stdshared-ptr-initialization-make-sharedfoo-vs-shared-ptrtnew-foo)