# Initialise std::shared_ptr using value initialisation

Tags: c++, c++14, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, value-initialization

I was experimenting with braced initialisation and specifically using value initialisation.

To my understanding `int x {}` uses value initialisation to set the value of x to 0.

So I then tried this with a `std::shared_ptr` and a trivial inner class `Foo`:
`std::shared_ptr<Foo> sharedFoo {}` and tried to call a function from sharedFoo. I was slightly surprised to see this resulted in a segmentation fault.

My intuition had made me think that this would be value initialised, using the default constructor for `Foo`. However, I then realised that sharedFoo has not actually had any memory allocated to it, using either `new Foo` or `std::make_shared`. Is my reasoning correct here. Is my reasoning correct here? I was hoping to default initialise a shared_ptr using simple braces.

My full code for reference is below:

```cpp
    #include <memory>
    #include <iostream>
    
    class Foo
    {
    public:
        int getValue() const { return value; }
    private:
        int value = 0;
    };
    
    int main()
    {
        int i {};
    
        std::shared_ptr<Foo> sharedFoo { };
    
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    
        std::cout << sharedFoo->getValue() << std::endl; //SEGFAULT
    
        return 0;
    }
```

For reference, my question is not the following: [std::shared_ptr initialization: make_shared<Foo>() vs shared_ptr<T>(new Foo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301511/stdshared-ptr-initialization-make-sharedfoo-vs-shared-ptrtnew-foo)

Really, the core of the question is why `int i {}` performs a value initialisation of `i`, but `std::shared_ptr<Foo> sharedFoo {}` does a default initialisation of sharedFoo and doesn't value initialise the contained pointer.

Comment: x86-64 gcc trunk. I've also updated the question to remove `new Foo`

Comment: Ok, that makes it clear. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::shared\_ptr initialization: make\_shared<Foo>() vs shared\_ptr<T>(new Foo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301511/stdshared-ptr-initialization-make-sharedfoo-vs-shared-ptrtnew-foo)
The question is a bit different, but the answer is applicable here as well.

Comment: @zerocukor287, no sorry that question is about the difference between std::make_shared and std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo). My question is about value initialisation of a std::shared_ptr

Comment: The core of your confusion seems to be that a `shared_ptr` (or even a raw pointer) _is_ an object in its own right. It is not the object it points to (if any). If you value-initialized a raw pointer that would also be `nullptr`.

Comment: @Useless value initialisation of a raw pointer being `nullptr` makes sense to me. But shared_ptr is just a thin wrapper around around a raw pointer, correct? So to me, it sounds like that is an object in its own right (and yes, not the object it points to, I understand that)

Comment: A raw pointer is an object, with a value. A `shared_ptr` is an object with a value _and constructors and behaviour and invariants_, but that doesn't change it from being pointer-like to somehow not existing at all and just being replaced by the object it points to. The value-initialized pointer doesn't point to anything, The value-initialized `shared_ptr` doesn't point to anything either, because that's how its default constructor is required to behave.

Comment: Yes, the `shared_ptr<Foo>` is an object in its own right and being a (semi) thin wrapper, you could see it as-if it's the pointer inside it that you initialize. `Foo* ptr{};` - if that makes sense. It's not a perfect analogy but for the usecase you have it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To my understanding `int x {}` uses value initialisation to set the value of x to 0.

Correct!

> Really, the core of the question is why `int i {}` performs a value initialisation of i, but `std::shared_ptr<Foo> sharedFoo {}` does a default initialisation of sharedFoo

Well, that's exactly what you asked it to do. [Value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) does different things for scalars (like `int`) and class objects with constructors.

This is because scalars *have* a well-defined zero value, whereas class types at most have a well-defined default constructor, which may have to establish some invariants before the object can be used.

If a class has only non-trivial constructors, you can't use an object of that class at all until the constructor has completed *because the object formally doesn't exist*. There's no reasonable "zero value" for such classes.

> and doesn't value initialise the contained pointer.

But it does. It does exactly that. Value initializing a pointer sets it to `nullptr`. You can't dereference that either.

> My intuition had made me think that this would be value initialised, using the default constructor for `Foo`

But you haven't declared any object of type `Foo` (let alone initialized it). You declared a (smart) pointer to `Foo`, and that's what you value-initialized.

You can, if you wish, *write* a smart pointer class that *always* creates an object of the contained type. But that isn't what `shared_ptr` does.

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<Foo> sharedFoo{};
```

`sharedFoo` is a default constructed, empty, `shared_ptr` and dereferencing it has undefined behavior. It does not own an object.

It's the same as-if you'd done:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<Foo> sharedFoo;
sharedFoo->getValue();
```

What you want is likely:

```cpp
auto sharedFoo = std::make_shared<Foo>();
```

Comment: I was expecting it to value construct a `Foo` object, like `int i {}` value constructs i to be equal to zero. Is this an exception to the rule or simply not the behaviour I should expect?

Comment: @HarryP2023 It's simply a default constructed (empty) `shared_ptr<Foo>`, not a `shared_ptr<Foo>` with a default constructed `Foo`

Comment: Ted Lyngmo thank you, so `std::shared_ptr<Foo> sharedFoo {}` performs a default construction whereas `int i {}` performs a value construction?

Comment: @HarryP2023 Yes, the `shared_ptr` is default-initialized, see: [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)

Comment: Well, [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) of an object with a default constructor _is_ default initialization (ie, the constructor is used). Value initialization of `int` or other scalars _is_ zero initialization. It's all listed.

Comment: Okay I see. So `std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo)` is value initialised?

Comment: No. You can read the documentation on [`initialization`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) instead of guessing: that would be _direct initialization_ (because you're explicitly passing a constructor argument)

Comment: The `Foo` is default-initialized by the `new` expression (you didn't give it any constructor arguments or a braced init list or anything) - which has the same effect as value-initializing would have in this case.

Comment: @HarryP2023 now matter how the constructor is invoked, its just a constructor, and the default constructor of the smart pointer does not create a `Foo`, because thats not what it is meant to be used for. It is meant to create an emtpy smart pointer.

Comment: @HarryP2023 • a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` models a **pointer** (a smart pointer, with federated ownership), not a **Foo**.

Answer (score 2):

The following two variable definitions

```
int i {};
std::shared_ptr<Foo> sharedFoo { };
```

**both** perform value-initialization.

It is also instructive to compare with:

```
Foo* p {};
```

In this case, `p` is initialized to a null pointer, because value-initialization for a pointer type always initializes it to a null pointer. It is unclear why you would expect value-initialization for a pointer to create an object for the pointer to point to.

Value-initialization of `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` calls the default constructor, and the result is that the `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` object is placed in a state that is logically similar to the value-initialized pointer state, *i.e.*, null.